# Solving equation with complex roots

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm solving the equation $$w^2 = \frac{-11}{4} -15i$$
 and I should thereafter use the answer to solve 
$$z^2-(3+4i)z+(1+21i)=0$$

I solve the first equation and get answers 
$$w_1 = \frac{5}{2}-3i$$ and $$w_2=-\frac{5}{2}+3i$$

I know how to go about part two of the question,
 but I can't figure out when I should use answers 
from part one of the question 
to solve part two.

What I've so far tried is 
that I've completed the brackets in part two:
$$ (z-3-4i)^2-(-3-4i)^2+(1+21i)=0$$

I've then substituted 
$(z-3-4i)^2$ for $w^2$ 
and set $w=(w_1)$ 
and in another part $w=(w_2)$ 
and then solved.

I get answers 
$$z_1=-\frac{71}{4}-8i$$
 and 
$$z_2=-\frac{107}{4}-18i$$
which, when controlled, 
doesn't equate the original equation to zero.

Any help or suggestions is highly appreciated!

Comment: That is very hard to read. I will reformat it. Please make sure that I have preserved the question.

Comment: Looks brilliant now! Thanks Marty

Comment: `I've completed the brackets in part two` That doesn't look right. Maybe recheck your calculations at that step.

Comment: I had a typo previously. I had written -(-3-4i)^3 yet it should be -(-3-4i)^2 but it's now edited. anymore suggestions @dxiv ?

Comment: The coefficients of $z^1$ still don't match by a factor of $2$, neither does the constant term.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you meant to solve something this

$$z^2-(3-4i)z+(1+12i)=0$$

$$a=1 \qquad b=-3+4i \qquad c=1+12i$$

\begin{align}
   z &= \dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \\
     &= \dfrac{3-4i \pm \sqrt{-7-12i-4-48i}}{2} \\
     &= \dfrac{3-4i \pm \sqrt{-11-60i}}{2} \\
     &= \dfrac{3-4i}{2} \pm \dfrac{5-6i}{2}
\end{align}

There are other possibilities that will work or I could just be wrong. You will have to work that out yourself.